# php simple_load_string always returning zero data on well formed xml docs

Tags: php, xml

I have been trying to load a number of XML files into a PHP page using a simple load string. Strange as this might sound, not one loads, and all return as `empty`.

I can load them using `$xmldoc = new DomDocument( '1.0' );` and I can view all directly in the browser. I'm getting really frustrated because I can't see why they should fail to load.

I am using offline development - Win7 proff, XAMPP Version: 1.8.1 with PHP 5.4 loaded.

Example of my simple loading code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('menu45.xml');
        if ( !$xml ) {
            echo "empty!!!!";
           // return 'Error';
        }
```

I am hoping someone will let me know if there is a problem with using a simple load string on a Windows machine or if there's a bug in PHP 5.4, or XAMPP has issues with it, or something.

I've Google'd and read everything I could for an 18 hour stint without joy. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've got a problem with a PHP function look into the php manual first: http://php.net/simplexml_load_string - `'menu45.xml'` is not a valid XML string.

Comment: Post the XML, if it's Long, in a shortened but VALID version

Comment: So you're using a function wrong. Maybe you also wrongfully think something would be valid XML as well? So show the XML here first.

Answer (score 1):

[simplexml_load_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) loads strings, not files.... and `"menu45.xml"` isn't a well formed xml string. Try [simplexml_load_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) instead.

Comment: And please leave a comment about errror reporting and logging. PHP *tells* what is going wrong, you only need to *listen*.

Comment: Thank you. I used an example off the w3c site which also used as you pointed out file(). That failed also (I should have pointed that out) <?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
 
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";
 
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
   {
   echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child->name . "<br>";
   }
 ?>  and formed mine as per their suggestion. This doesnt return . I tried var dump and get bool(false).  I have read the php manueal, I have also copied numerioud examples fronm site point. I have as illustrated used the =w3c example. I dont know what else to try.

Comment: w3schools is __not__ a good site for learning PHP (or much else either) because it has too many mistakes and inaccuracies

Comment: Try using libxml_use_internal_errors() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) with libxml_get_errors() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) to diagnose what problems the simpleXML reader believes it has found in the file

Comment: Thank you. I've done all of that and mre.There are no errors reported which is why I am so flumuxed.I just get an empty file. I have deliberately caused errors to make sure and of course those are trapped. I have tried many examples from xml books, online, ur site. Not one example tried has returned a populated file. Hence the angle my question took, i.e. could it be something beyond the code? The examples in the main are about as simple as they can get. I guess this isn't gpoing to get resolved. THank you for your response and guidance. Cheers

Comment: Perhaps the XML isn't as well formed as you think - can you post a sample?